# Using mod_rewrite to bypass PHP framework for image, js, and css files

Tags: php, .htaccess, frameworks

We are using a popular PHP framework to host a website.

We made some additions that allow us to do custom modules that encapsulate controllers, service objects, PHP templates, Javascript, CSS, and images into a single sub-directory.

We created it outside the vendor directory to distinguish these modules from third-party libraries.

What I want to do is have Apache 2.2. serve up the images, js, and css in these modules instead of going through PHP.

I have tried to edit the .htaccess file to return the files directly. It isn't working and I can't seem to find documentation on how to do this.

The URLs are in the format:

`https://example.com/Modules/cart/images/shopping_cart.png`
`https://example.com/Modules/cart/js/shopping_cart.js`
`https://example.com/Modules/cart/css/shopping_cart.css`

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Modules/(.*)/images/(.*)$
RewriteCond /var/www/app/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^/Modules/(.*)/images/(.*)$ /var/www/app/Modules/$1/images/$2 [L]
```

What am I missing?

**Edited to add:**
The Modules directory is outside the document root `/var/www/public` of the virtual host, so they are currently being served through PHP. I am actually trying to optimize a currently running site.

**[UPDATE]**

As per the info given by @Dave I have created a symbolic link from a sub-directory the document root to the images directory of the module.

So the symbolic link is in the form `[document root]/images/[module name]/` pointing to `/var/www/app/Modules/[module name]/images/`.

However I'm still getting the following headers indicating it is going through PHP:

```
Request URL: https://example.com/Modules/cart/images/shopping_cart.png
Server: Apache/2.4.35 (FreeBSD)
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10
```

My new rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Modules/(.*)/images/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/$1/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^/Modules/(.*)/images/(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that they are going to be going through PHP? The browser requests those resources directly and PHP would not be involved.

Comment: The headers on the response indicate it is going through PHP. The Modules directory is outside the document root of the Virtual Host.

Comment: In that case I don't believe there is a way to accomplish it since Apache can't _see_ anything above the document root.

Comment: Based on your edit I would suggest that you move the static resources such as the `.js` and `.css` files someplace where Apache will be able to see them. That would also allow them to be cached which will help your overall performance since they shouldn't need to be served as often.

Comment: @Dave I was trying to avoid doing symbolic links in the document root since we have dozens of modules. Of course we don't want the PHP source available in the document root, so we would have to link the static resources separately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. For those who may be wondering what the final answer is I'll detail it here.

I created symbolic links into our modules so that Apache can see them relative to the document root in the following format:

```
[document root]/images/[module name]/ pointing to /var/www/app/Modules/[module name]/images/
[document root]/css/[module name]/ pointing to /var/www/app/Modules/[module name]/css/
[document root]/js/[module name]/ pointing to /var/www/app/Modules/[module name]/js/
```

Then the rewrite rule is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Modules/(.*)/(js|css|images)/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2/%1/%3 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)Modules/(.*)/(js|css|images)/(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$3/$2/$4 [L]
```

Now we can transition on a case by case basis to the new locations while still speeding up the old code.